# Show that every other proper subgroup of $QD_{16}$ is contained in one of these three subgroups.

Tags: group-theory

This is the second part of the problem [Find three subgroups of $QD16$ of order $8$, and find the isomorphism type of each group.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4694464/855456) which is

> Show that every other proper subgroup of $QD_{16}$ is contained in one of these three subgroups.

I have already found the three subgroups of order $8$ which are $\langle σ \rangle,\langle σ^2,τ \rangle$ and $ \langle τσ,σ^2 \rangle$ . Clearly these groups are normal subgroup of $G$ and I think these are maximal normal subgroups.

But I have no idea to show that every other proper subgroup of $QD_{16}$ is contained in one of these three subgroups.

I think I have to show taking any proper subgroup $H$ of $QD_{16}$ and show that which is a subset of one of these three subgroups.

Can anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Any proper subgroup is contained in a maximal subgroup; every maximal subgroup of a group of order $p^n$ is of order $p^{n-1}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin thank you it is a new thing for me.